# Iterate through list in dictionary values in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary with almost 2000 keys, and every key has list as a value (with almost 2000 element in list). 
Something like this:
dict

```
 { 'a' : [1, 0, 42, 53...], 'b' : [6, 52, 0, 23],...}
```

What I need to do is to take min value for each key in dict, except 0, 0 is need to be dropped. 
Desired output:

```
{ 'a' : '1', 'b' : '6', ...}
```

I have tried with:

```
new_dict = { k:v for k, v in dict.items() if v!=0 }
```

But nothing happen

Comment: `v` is a list, of course its `!= 0`

Comment: @Julien Drop zeros, for start.

Comment: `k: min(e for e in v if e)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there, this is what you want:

```
new_dict = { k:min(x for x in v if x != 0) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Note: don't use the keyword `dict` for your variable name...

Comment: I have write a demo `b={k: min([i for i in v if i > 0]) for k, v in a.items()} `, but you answer quick! so no answer anymore!

Comment: @PeterWood for filter `0` item

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `filter` function:

```
final_data = {a:min(filter(lambda x:x != 0, b)) for a, b in data.items()}
```

Comment: Also Pythonic! But `lambda` is a little bit difficult to understand!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative that may be more easier to read if you are more comfortable with straight for-loops:

```
d = {'a' : [1, 0, 42, 53], 'b' : [6, 52, 0, 23]}

new_dict = {}
for key, list_value in d.items():
  new_dict[key] = min(filter(lambda x: x != 0, list_value))

print(new_dict) # {'a': 1, 'b': 6}
```